# Cannot find exact id for mysql row

Tags: mysql

I have table ct_table:

```
id    number     art    vaegt   
398    72        Laks    7500      *   
399    34        Laks    6420      *   
400    2901      Laks    5600   
401    29        Laks    10400   
403    29        Laks    12750     *   
404    2901      Laks    11250     *
```

Now I want to select the ID's for the * ones. That is the highest vaegt for each art, pr number.
But i'm running in the problem, that no matter what I do, I get the right vaegts and number, but the wrong ID's. I'm getting the id 401 for number 29, but it shoul be 403. I have not added my select statement, because I don't want to mess up your thoughts :)
I hope that someone can help, because I believed that is was easy, but I cannot get it right.

My failing query:

```
 SELECT id, number, art, max(vaegt) FROM ct_table WHERE storfanger=1 GROUP BY art, number
```

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: version
10.3.27-MariaDB-1:10.3.27+maria~focal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start be getting a table of the number and max vaegt

```
select number,max(vaegt) as vaegt from ct_table group by number;
```

Then join the original table back to get the full record

```
select ori.* from
(select number,max(vaegt) as vaegt from ct_table group by number) as base
join ct_table as ori
on 
  base.number = ct_table.number and
  base.vaegt = ct_table.vaegt
;
```

Comment: So that actually works, Thanks... BUT.. what if there is another ID with that exact same vaegt? Will that be handled in that statement?

Comment: This will put both those records in the final result. If you only want one you will need to be more specific about which one you want